# How many integers less than 2015 are multiples of 2 or 3 (or both)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Here is what I did.

To find all the multiples of 2 that is less than 2015 all we need to do is
divide by 2. The same can be done for multiples of 3 that is less than 2015:

2015 / 2 = 1007 (Integers multiples of 2)

2015 / 3 = 671 (Integers multiples of 2)

2015 / 6 = 335

( 1007 + 671 ) - 355 = 1344 Answer

Comment: What is your question. Is it about whether or not you are correct? You are.

Comment: @mixedmath I think he made a couple of mistakes. I get 1343.

Comment: @bof: Oh, is he off by $1$? I must admit, I really meant the methodology was correct. Whoops/

Comment: For "671 (Integers multiples of **2**)" read "671 (integer multiples of **3**)". For "(1007 + 671) -3**5**5"  read "(1007 + 671) - 3**3**5". For "134**4**" read "134**3**".

Comment: $1007+671-335=1343$!!!

Comment: Since the question is abou tintegers **less than** 2015, that is, integers **less than or equal to** 2014, you should be dividing 2014 instead of 2015 by 2, 3, and 6. You get the same answer because 2015 itself is not divisible by 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3):

Your method (using the in-and-out formula) is correct, although your work (at least the version you posted) is kind of sloppy. Here is another way:

Out of every six consecutive integers, four are divisible by $2$ or $3$; namely, $6n+2,6n+3,6n+4,6n+6$ are divisible by $2$ or $3$ (or both), while $6n+1,6n+5$ are not. Simce $2014=335\times6+4,$ the number of integers in $[1,2015)$ which are divisible by $2$ or $3$ is $335\times4+3=1343.$

Answer (score -1):

an alternate method would be using AP

for example divisors of 2

2,4,6........2014

using

nth term = first term +(number of terms - 1)common difference

2014=2+(n-1)2

n=1007

similarly you can easily solve for

3,6,9........,2013
and thus for 
6,12,18........2010